# Совместная разработка на Python

Tags: python, развертывание

Как совместно работать с одним Python проектом нескольким людям ? Понятно что через VCS можно совместно работать с кодом, но как быть с целым проектом ?
Т.е. как быть уверенным что у всех участников проекта будет одна версия компилятора и все зависимости ? Т.е. меня скорее интересует процесс автоматического развертывания, но не для конечного пользователя который сможет просто запустить приложение, а для некоторого абстрактного разработчика, который сможет очень быстро получить все что нужно ему для разработки на его целевой платформе и уже настроенное и рабочее.

Comment: Это конечно от проекта зависит. Общий ответ, может объёма книги потребовать (материала на несколько полок хватит). В одном случае, достаточно инструкцию написать (с командами типа git,apt-get,pip,conda), в другом docker, vm с помощью vagrant up поднимать, в третьем админ заклинания для ansible/chef/puppet/salt/etc выполнит, ещё где-то достаточно fabric скрипт запустить или одно из миллиона решений по оркестрации типа http://kubernetes.io/ применить (это не упоминая CI и ещё кучу интересных слов): разные проекты—разные требования.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, создать следующие файлы.

requirements, в котором будет что-то вроде:

```
tornado==4.3
redis==2.10.3
fuzzywuzzy==0.7.0
```

и setup.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

VENV=.venv
LOGDIR=./log

rm -rf $VENV
rm -rf $LOGDIR

mkdir $LOGDIR

virtualenv $VENV
source $VENV/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements
```

В первом, соответственно, зависимости; во втором - скрипт развертки.
А потом, как обычно, можно спокойно пользоваться VCS.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [Pyenv](https://khashtamov.com/2015/12/pyenv-python/)
Через него устанавливаем нужную версию python, например 3.5.2:

```
$ pyenv install 3.5.2
```

Переходим в каталог проекта и создаём виртуальное окружение для него:

```
$ pyenv virtualenv 3.5.2 my_prog_venv
$ cd my_prog
$ pyenv local my_prog_venv
$ ln -s $PYENV_ROOT/versions/3.5.2/envs/my_prog_venv venv
```

Обновляем в нём pip и доставляем нужные для проекта пакеты:

```
$ pip install -U pip
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Здесь requirements.txt - предварительно подготовленный для проекта файл со списком зависимостей.
Делается простой коммандой:

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

И удалением ненужных если они есть. :)